# Moving Docker Containers Around

Tags: docker

I would like to use this Docker container:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cptactionhank/atlassian-confluence/dockerfile/

My concern is that if I have to wind up moving this docker container to another machine (or it quits for some reason and needs to be restarted) that all the data (server config and other items stored on the file system) is lost. How do I ensure that this data isn't lost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of Docker containers is don't locate your data *inside* your application container.  Data that needs to persist beyond the lifetime of the container should be stored in a Docker "volume", either mounted from a host directory or from a data-only container.

If you want to be able to start containers on different hosts and still have access to your data, you need to make sure your data is available on those hosts.  This problem isn't unique to Docker; it's the same problem you would have if you wanted to scale an application across hosts without using Docker.

Solutions include:

- A network filesystem like NFS.
- A cluster fileystem like Gluster.
- A non-filesystem based data store, like a database, or something like Amazon S3.

This is not necessarily an exhaustive list but hopefully gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you... this is very helpful. How does mounting a docker volume work? Does it need to exist outside the container first?... or does building the docker container with VOLUME ['/x/y/z'] create the necessary directories?

Comment: Those questions probably require more of an answer than is appropriate for the comments here.  [This](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) document is a good place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... -v /webapp would create a volume *inside* the container at /webapp. I just tried this as an example and there's no /webapp on the host. How, then, is the /webapp data accessed once the container is destroyed?

Comment: I think a closer reading of the document I linked in my previous comment will answer that question.  If you have additional questions, you may want to post them as new questions here on the site rather than as comments on this answer.